# Dynamic Reporting Day in Tableau Dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I have been trying my hands on something in Tableau and finding it hard to implement. I have attached my sample workbook and the data source I am using from excel. The second tab in Excel shows the final dashboards I want to see as the end result; the first of which I have accomplished in Tableau using the desktop version.

There are 5 kinds of products for which the quality runs happen at different times. My goal is to return the 'Result' of the product based on the latest available 'Quality Run Time' which is 29th March 2018. I got to this part using two calculated fields below:

```
{FIXED [Product] : MAX([Quality Run Time])} as 'Max_Date'

IF [Quality Run Time] = [Max_Date] THEN [Result] END as 'Max_Result'
```

The result of this is in the workbook. The problem is I want a dynamic 'Reporting Period' filter for the user to be able to choose from available dates in the 'Quality Run Time.' For example if I wanted to run a report for 27th March 2018, based on the logic I should see the dashboard below (ex from Tab 2 in Excel). I am guessing my calculated fields need to be dynamic somehow and I have tried many different options but it hasn't worked yet.

> [Please pickup data source and workbook from here](https://community.tableau.com/message/744977#744977)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic doesn't work as expected.

You need to create a parameter with datatype DATE and then use that in filter.

I have changed the report and attached in the same link.

I have changed in Tableau version 10.5

Edit---------------------------------------------------

Updated with v10.4 in same link

Comment: Hey Shiva, Can you please downgrade your workbook and re-share? I am using 10.4. Thanks!

Comment: @SyedAsghar you can check link and update me incase still you have any issue

Comment: Thanks @Siva. The parameter doesn't work when I select March 29th. It gives all available quality run time results per product while it should only give the latest result.

Comment: Can you elaborate latest result mean... as per the excel sheet report works.. so if you select March 29 then all the dates will be displayed prior to march 29.. this is what I understood from excel... are you not looking for this kind of result